# Chunk Loading glitches

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Sometimes, when I set my render distance to a certain higher level, some chunks clone themselves then flash from underground, to the sky, and back and forth.

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Could you give a video or a screenshot?

Comment: Give us a Video or a Screen-shot of it.

Answer (score 1):

If it looks something like this:

[image]

.. then you are likely experiencing [[MC-62958]](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-62958). The solutions to it are:

- Go to <kbd>Options</kbd> -> <kbd>Video Settings</kbd> and turn <kbd>Use VBOs: ON</kbd>
- Turn down your render distance
- Update your graphics drivers

Comment: Thanks, but since I updated to the new launcher, it stopped. I dont know, why it did, but the glitches stopped. Thank you for the tip, though, in case this glitch pops up again! :D